# Which model relationship should I be using?

Tags: django

I have the following in my models.py

```
class items(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    item_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='itemimage/', default=None, blank=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100)        

class comparelist(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    item1 = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    item2 = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    item3 = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    item4 = models.ForeignKey(items, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
```

The idea is to allow a user to add 4 different items to their account so they can compare them.

But when I makemigrations, I get the following error:

```
compareapp.comparelist.item1: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'comparelist.item1' clashes with reverse accessor for 'comparelist.item2'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'comparelist.item1' or 'comparelist.item2'.
```

I'm assuming ForeignKey is not the relationship field to use here.
I tried reading django docs on relationship fields but I can't get my head around it.

Can someone give me a simple explanation on the 3 different relationship fields? And which one should be used in this situation?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a [Many-to-many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/#many-to-many-relationships) relationship, since you want multiple items in your compare list, but you also probably want the items to be on multiple lists. To limit the amount of many-to-many relationships a list has, you could write a custom method to add new items, for example:

```py
class CompareList(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    items = models.ManyToManyField(items, related_name='compare_lists')

    def add_item(self, item):
        if self.items.count() < 4:
            self.items.add(item)
        else:
            raise Exception('List limit reached')
```

Comment: Much appreciated! However I also found out that ForeignKey also works as long as you give each one a different related name. I think the positive of a ForeignKey in this situation is that you can see the items in the admin table, whereas ManyToMany don't show what's selected.

Comment: Also I just tested that the items used on one list can still be used on another list by using ForeignKey. So why is that a feature for ManyToMany?